# Django template doesn't render properly. Prints DTL tags as regular text

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm in the middle of creating a base.html template for my very first Django project. Unfortunately, i've already encountered a problem. My DTL tags are visible in a browser for some reason, it gets printed out like a regular text.

Here is my code (as you can see I didn't even start doing anything yet):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Base</title>
    {% block head %}

    {% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}
        <h1>Base</h1>
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Here is what i get:
[image: in a browser]

How do a get rid of it?? Do i need some sort of extension for this?? Or where in the settings should I look for the problem? I have absolutely no clue.

Comment: Please share the view where you render this template.

Comment: You are not using Django here. URL from screenshot is clearly saying that you're browsing _files from hard drive_. To start _using django_ define url patterns and navigate defined urls.

Comment: Thank you, @Ivan-Starostin. You were right! The problem was i forgot to map my app/urls.py to urlpatterns in my root dir urls.py. Also i was viewing my pages with LiveServer instead of running a server. Now that I map it in root dir and run a server with manage.py it all works properly!